# How can i move a widget left and right until the available space is filled?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm a beginner and still learning flutter, please forgive me if am getting something wrong here.

So i have a Stack inside of which i have 2 Widgets. Widget1 and Widget2.
I want to center the Widget B right below Widget A.

NOTE: Widget 2 is larger than Widget1.

```
 class MyWidgets extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
         Widget1,
         Positioned(
           top: widget1PositionFromTop + widget1Size,
           left: widget1PositionFromLeft,
           child: FractionalTranslation(
             translation: Offset(-0.5, 0.0),
             child: Widget2,
           ),
         )
       ],

     );
   }
 }
```

The Problem is, if the Widget1's position from left is 0, or less than half the size of Widget2, the Widget2 is overflowed, and only half or a part of the Widget2 can be seen.

I want to know how can i only translate its position as long as there is space left, i mean if there is space left only for 0.3 of Widget2 then it will move only -0.3 not -0.5..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this using `Stack` then

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(width: 200, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
          Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

which gives

[image: Stack result]

---

Maybe you could use `Column` like

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(width: 200, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
          Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

with the end result as

[image: Column result]

Comment: Thanks but your not getting the point. please read the question again. I have no problem here. The problem is when i want  to center my Widget2 using fractional translation at the bottom center  of  Widget1 (NOTE: in my case Widget 2 is larger than Widget1), it overflows when it is near the edge of the screen.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your requirement vs what you are getting?